# codeIgniter google maps api V3 coordinates

Tags: codeigniter, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I use map from demo to location person [geolocation map](http://biostall.com/demos/google-maps-v3-api-codeigniter-library/geolocation) my problem is that i want to save the coordinates to database but i dont know how?

Comment: More precisely my problem is that I can not get the coordinates I do nt know where they are located.

Answer (score 0):

Use google and curl to encode a location... Here is an example function i've written and have in use now on a production site:

```
//$loc can be any kind of location from 555 street name, city, st, zip to just city, state, etc.

$loc = 'Austin, TX';    
function get_geo_loc($loc) {
          $string = str_replace (" ", "+", urlencode($loc));
           $details_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$string."&sensor=false";

           $ch = curl_init();
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $details_url);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
           $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);

           $lat = $response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
           $lng = $response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];

          return array(
             'lat' => $lat,
             'lng' => $lng
          );
       }
```